How to create nested table with rowspan and colspan?
I have a data coming from an API which look like:
{
    "fiscal_year": "2023",
    "quarter": "FY23 - Q1",
    "A": 157,
    "B": 122,
    "C": 392,
    "A_yoy": 0.4,
    "B_yoy": 0.008,
    "C_yoy": 0.21
} 

I need to create a vue.js table similar to the one in the picture. I am not sure how to structure the data to achieve what is inside the table.

Code:
const structuredItems = {};
const Quarters = new Set();

self.dataFQMIssues.forEach(entry => {
    const { fiscal_year, quarter, A, B, C, D, E, F };
  
    Quarters.add(quarter);
  
    if (!structuredItems[fiscal_year]) {
        structuredItems[fiscal_year] = [
          { label: 'Open', items: [] },
          { label: 'Execution', items: [] }
        ];
    }
  
    structuredItems[fiscal_year][0].items.push({ item: 'A', value: A });
    structuredItems[fiscal_year][1].items.push({ item: 'E', value: E });
});

self.dataItem = structuredItems;
self.quarters = Array.from(Quarters);


What have you tried? Were is your component code?

I tried to structure the data but not sure if it is correct , here is how I did it , I am trying to post the code but it is too long

<const structuredItems = {};
const Quarters = new Set();
self.dataFQMIssues.forEach(
entry => {const { fiscal_year,quarter,A,B,C,D,E,F};
Quarters.add(quarter);  if (!structuredItems[fiscal_year]) {
structuredItems[fiscal_year] = [ {label: 'Open', items: [] },{ label: 'Execution',                   items: [] },]; }
structuredItems[fiscal_year][0].items.push({ item: 'A', value: A });
structuredItems[fiscal_year][1].items.push({ item: 'E', value: E });
});    self.dataItem = structuredItems; self.quarters = Array.from(Quarters);>

I added the code to your post (you can edit it yourself). Did you mean to destructure the fields from the entry? Your syntax looks off.

what I am aiming for is to have each year with the four quarters and the corresponding data for A, B, C not sure if I did it correctly I was searching online and asked Chat GPT for help
